# Xcode 9 undefined symbols for architecture x86_64

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, llvm, xcode9

after switching to Xcode 9 I am getting errors, it looks like this.

[image]

I blanked the project and classes names, but there is a list of classess ending with .o suffix. In Xcode 8.3.2 everything works. I  got 2 projects, one is library that is building without problems. Another project is test app, that is pointing to the library by :path directive in Podfile. In both projects build settings -> architectures is set to standard arichitectures, build active architectures only is set to DEBUG: Yes, RELEASE: No. Have you come across this problem? Thanks upfront for the   help.

Comment: your pod is updated or not

Comment: i just updated them, but same errors

Comment: are you tried in device or simulator, your file does not support simulator

Comment: It does support simulator, in Xcode 8.3.2 I was testing on both simulator and device, in Xcode 9 neither simulator or device are working

Comment: Can you show us pod files

Comment: Try the [cocoapods-deintegrate](https://github.com/CocoaPods/cocoapods-deintegrate) to unload all the pod dependency and run `pod install` again, the app target's build settings will be ***refresh*** in Pods project again.

Comment: I tried this also and no help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I ran build for profiling, it was working, but with classic build there were mentioned errors. After searching through logs it seems there is some weird behaviour with flags, particularly -fprofile-instr-generate. The solution was to set flag Enable Code Coverage to No in build settings of the library project. This was shooting into the dark but somehow got it working.

Answer (score 7):

Ran into similar problem. Just post it here in case it can help anyone.

Was using class *AbcService* from a framework (written in Swift 3 and by ourselves) in our app's Objective-c class B. After upgrading from Xcode8/Swift3 to Xcode9/Swift4 it failed  to build an archive for the **release** config, due to `Undefined symbols` error of this class during linking:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
   "_OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC15XxxabcServices17AbcService", referenced from:
```

The weird thing is, it worked fine to archive the **debug** config, and for running in emulator.

Spent almost 1 day to find out the root cause: the Swift class *AbcService* in the framework was missing a **`public`** modifier.

Answer (score 4):

Simple trick here: Go -> Go To Folder "/Library/Developer/Xcode" delete Derived data next clean your project then Run .

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Cocoapods you most likely need to update those.

That means you need to do a `pod update` on the command line inside your project's directory and then rebuild your project in Xcode.

In general when using a new major version of Xcode it is necessary to rebuild all components. Your error message is telling you that the object files you already have (the *.o files are basically what the compiler produces out of your source files) are not compatible with newly compiled object files (the linker which is complaining in your case has the purpose of combining or 'linking' together all the object files).

It might sometimes be necessary to clean your derived data (the stuff Xcode caches). You can do this by going to Xcode's `Product` menu and while holding down the Option/Alt key, pick the menu item 'clean build folder'.

Comment: I did pod update in both projects, cleaned the build folder the way you suggested, but still these error popped out.

Comment: What Swift version did you set in both projects?

Are you sure the referenced framework in your test app isn't some old framework instead of the one you are freshly building?

Comment: You could remove the dependecy from your app from the linked frameworks and drag it in again

Comment: These are both objective-C projects. I am sure I am referencing the right project.

Comment: Then it might be helpful if you could provide the build log. In the left inspector pane go to the last tab and you'll see all recent builds. Select the last build and you'll see the log in the main editor. can you post that somehow? (You can find/replace stuff in a texteditor to obscure things if you like)

Comment: This issue has happened to me twice. One of the two times running `pod update` solved the issue. The other time I had to do something else, not sure exactly what it might have been deleting the derived data